# Jquery selector based on inline CSS style or span text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

I am trying to select a span if it fits under certain conditions. First criteria is inline CSS which is
`style="width:0% !important;"`
Second is span text, which is

```
<span class="bv-rating-label">   (0)  </span>
```

Here is complete HTML code:

```
<div class="bv-inline-rating-container">
<dl class="bv-stars-container" role="presentation">
    <dd class="bv-rating-ratio" role="presentation">
        <span class="bv-rating-stars-container">
            <span class="bv-rating-stars bv-rating-stars-off" aria-hidden="true">  ★★★★★  </span>
            <span class="bv-rating-stars-on bv-rating-stars" style="width:0% !important;" aria-hidden="true">  ★★★★★  </span>
        </span>
    </dd>
    <dd class="bv-rating-ratio-count" role="presentation">
        <span class="bv-rating-label">   (0)  </span>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Here are some options that I tried.
Option 1 :

```
jQuery(".bv-rating-label:contains('   (0)  ')").hide();
```

Option 2 :

```
jQuery('.bv-rating-stars-on.bv-rating-stars[style*="width:0% !important"]).hide();
```

None of the options above worked :/

Comment: your first option itself is working fine. Check the plunker.  https://plnkr.co/edit/l50wCt1vXBYoINcgJ76I?p=preview

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking and which span (or spans?) you want to select from your quoted structure.

Comment: Hey Deep. Thanks for your response. You are right. This option worked. I just had to modify jquery little bit. 
`jQuery(".bv-rating-label:contains('   (0)  ')").attr("style", "display: none !important")`

Answer (score 0):

I put your question into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63ajLx4g/).

I was able to hide the elements based on their respective attributes and the text value they hold.

If you don't want to go to the JSFiddle, here is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bv-inline-rating-container">
<dl class="bv-stars-container" role="presentation">
    <dd class="bv-rating-ratio" role="presentation">
        <span class="bv-rating-stars-container">
            <span class="bv-rating-stars bv-rating-stars-off" aria-hidden="true">  ★★★★★  </span>
            <span class="bv-rating-stars-on bv-rating-stars" style="width:0% !important;" aria-hidden="true">  ★★★★★test  </span>
        </span>
    </dd>
    <dd class="bv-rating-ratio-count" role="presentation">
        <span class="bv-rating-label">   (0)  </span>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bv-rating-label:contains('(0)')").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bv-rating-stars-on, .bv-rating-stars[style='width:0% !important']").hide();
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be diffent. Using class is more generic. Why don't you use an Id?

```
$('#yourId').hide();
```

But if you want to use one class inside the other it's also possible:

```
$('.yourclass.innerClass').hide();
```

Then you can try tris examples below:

```
$('.bv-rating-stars-on, .bv-rating-stars[style="width:0%!important"]').hide();
$('.bv-rating-ratio-count .bv-rating-label').hide();
$('.bv-rating-stars-container .bv-rating-stars').hide();
```

Best Regards

Comment: Hey Jeff, I don't have an access to edit HTML, thats the problem. Otherwise, I would be glad to use that option.

Comment: I've made this examples to you: $('.bv-rating-stars-on, .bv-rating-stars[style="width:0% !important"]').hide();
$('.bv-rating-ratio-count .bv-rating-label').hide();
$('.bv-rating-stars-container .bv-rating-stars').hide();